# laravel 5.1 auth login returns an error

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to use `auth()->login()` in laravel 5.1 but it returns an error. Please see my code below:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->where('activation_code', $activation_code);
$not_activated_user = $user->where('status', 0)->where('confirmed', 0);

if($not_activated_user->count() == 1){
    $not_activated_user->update([
        'status' => 1,
        'confirmed' => 1
    ]);

    auth()->login($user->where('status', 1)->where('confirmed', 1));
}
```

I've also import `use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;` and `implements AuthenticatableContract` in my `User` model, but it still returns the same error. Why is that? I also tried to use `->get()` in `->login(....->get())` to get the current user, but still same error.

**Error:**

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given`

Comment: The whole thing is messed up.. Can you uniquely identify the user from their username?  And you want to log them in with no password or any other form of identity as long as they are status=1 and confirmed=1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)->where('activation_code', $activation_code)->firstOrFail();
$user->update([
    'status' => 1,
    'confirmed' => 1
    ]);

    auth()->login($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, I just called the `User` model again to select the current user :)